# Events subscribing equivalent of "+= Tab Tab" in C# VS IDE

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, code-snippets

I wonder what is (if is) the "shortcut"(code-snippet) for adding handlers in VB.NET (Visual Studio 2005/08), equivalent to the `+=` + `Tab` + `Tab` in `button1.Click += ...` C# IDE.

In this way C# IDE auto-creates the necessary method, with all necessary parameters.
So, If I know that I need to execute a method at a event *even if I don't know the function implementation signature* I do `MyEvent+=TabTab` and I just write the method's code.

So `AddHandler button1.Click`*`???`*

***Nota Bene***

I am asking about a object not (necessarily) linked with the Visual Studio Form's designer. Suppose my button is a private one in a custom class or is a button generated by some code, or, in general my button is a any object that implement an event...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AddHandler button1.Click, AddressOf MethodName

Unless you're taking about auto-creating the method which C# does, then I have no idea :/